# How to transfer data from a version to default version in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, versioning

I have lost all data from default version and also from the base tables in Oracle. But luckily, there is a version that has all the data in it. I have reconciled and posted that version to default but since the data is already there in that version and I haven't made any changes yet therefore default version is still empty.

Is there any way to restore the data from that version to default version?

I don't want to import data in base tables directly but from ArcMap so that I can bring everything to its original state.

Comment: If your database instance has been horrifically corrupted, you really ought to be talking to Tech Support.  They can talk you though the procedures necessary to preserve whatever you have left. At this point, you should have a sequestered *before* backup, an *as-is* database backup, and be prepared to rollback to the *before* backup.

Comment: Maybe the database is not corrupt, someone might have deleted the data mistakenly. Is there any option to rollback to previous state?

Comment: Use your last full backup before the corruption. Or talk to Tech Support

Comment: If you can see the data in a child version but not in default then the first thing I would do is export to a new feature class from that version so you have a copy of the data. After that you can try restoring from backups or other approaches. If they fail at least you can reload from your copy.

Comment: How can I load the data in default version rather than base table?

Comment: @Dowlers if he can create a new version and append data through Arcmap from the new feature class he created by exporting from previous version and then reconsie and post the new version. It will work or not?

Comment: Personally instead of appending to a new version I would delete the feature class and rename the exported copy.

Comment: But if your geodatabase has corruption you need to fix it or the problem could easily reoccur. At the minimum I would unregister all FCs, delete all versions and compress to zero state. Vince has the most ideal solution though, restore a DB copy from before the corruption.